# How to configue email notifications alert on cisco prime infrastructure 3.0

Tags: cisco-catalyst

Well, I'm trying to configure email notifications alert on our Cisco Prime Infrastructure v.3.0, so that I´ll be able to receive email alerts, for instance, when any interface, devices like router, access points, switches and even server goes off or down, or gives any error on its interface.

I'm kind of a little new in this industry, but able to configure.

So can someone kindly help me with a straight-forward guide that helps me to accomplish this problem?

Comment: Do you have SMTP settings set already and just need to configure the actual alerts?

Comment: Thanks alot for your time and comment. And sorry for takibg a little long to reply, as iam in Africa and we got a big time difference but nevertheless here we go. So lets asdume i aint got the SMTP configured yet. I got nothing done yet. Really Hope you can guidbme as well with that. Taking in consideratopn as id im starting. I thank you once again. Please Advice

Comment: You first need a SMTP server configured -- but that is off topic for this forum.  Then it's a simple matter to have Prime send email alerts to it.

Comment: Yes Tedwin. I got a MS Exchange Server running Set.
I simply just need to configure alerts and motification please Jhom

Comment: What I'm saying is that you first need to configure the setting in Prime so it can send your alerts out to your server for delivery.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Configuring Email Notifications for SNMP Traps](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/net_mgmt/prime/infrastructure/3-0/administrator/guide/PIAdminBook/SNMPTraps.html#48718)
[image]